# Swift - UIImage image causes nil value when presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

My app was working and has 2 views (home, detail).

I added a Image View to the homeView and built an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageTitle: UIImageView!
```

In the viewDidAppear I placed:

```
var title = UIImage(named: "image1")
imageTitle.image = title
```

The app works and displays my image, but when I move to the next view it produces the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

The action to move fails on:

```
self.presentViewController(detailView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

How do I fix this issue

Comment: is detailview not nil?

Comment: no, the link works in all other cases. I could be mistaken though

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the type of the image is it png or jpg.

```
let title = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
 imageTitle.image = title
```